# Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find its limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm currently having a lot of trouble with this problem. I'm not sure what tests I should use to apply to figure out whether this sequence converges or not. The sequence is defines as

$$ a_n=\ln \bigg( \arctan \bigg( \frac{e^n+6}{e^n+2} \bigg) \bigg), \ n \in \mathbb{N} .$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: It's 2 **continuous** functions applied after a fraction. I suggest you start from the inside, with the fraction. Can you solve the limit of that fraction only? If yes, can you find the limit if you apply $\tan^{-1}$? If yes, what if you finally apply $\ln$?

Answer (score 2):

We see that

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \ \frac{ e^n +6 }{ e^n +2 } = \frac{ 1+ \frac{6}{e^n} }{ 1 +\frac{2}{e^n} } $$

and we also know that

$$ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}: \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a}{e^n} = 0.  $$

Hence, we can conclude that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ 1+ \frac{6}{e^n} }{ 1 +\frac{2}{e^n} } =1.  $$

Since both $\ln$ and $\arctan$ are continuous functions on their domain, we see that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = \ln ( \arctan( 1)) = \ln \bigg( \frac{\pi}{4} \bigg ) \doteq -0.24. $$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that,
$$
\frac{e^n+6}{e^n+2}=\frac{1+\frac{6}{e^n}}{e^n+2}
$$
and,
$$
1 \leq \frac{1+\frac{6}{e^n}}{e^n+2} \leq \frac{7}{3}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
then, since $x \mapsto \tan^{-1} x$ and $x \mapsto \ln x$ are continuous and increasing functions $\forall x \in \mathbb{R_+}$,
$$
\ln{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \ln{\left(\tan^{-1}{\left(1\right)}\right)} \leq a_n \leq \ln{\left(\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)}\right)}
$$
which means that $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, hence converges.
Then you can easily compute the limit, which evaluates to $\ln{\frac{\pi}{4}}$.